# Use of scipy sparse in ode solver

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, scientific-computing

I am trying to solve a differential equation system

x´=Ax with x(0) = f(x)

in python, where A indeed is a complex sparse matrix.

For now i have been solving the system using the scipy.integrate.complex_ode class in the following way.

```
def to_solver_function(time,vector):
    sendoff = np.dot(A, np.transpose(vector))
    return sendoff

solver = complex_ode(to_solver_function)
solver.set_initial_value(f(x),0)

solution = [f(x)]
for time in time_grid:
    next = solver.integrate(time)
    solution.append(next)
```

This has been working OK, but I need to "tell the solver" that my matrix is sparse. I figured out that i should use

```
Asparse = sparse.lil_matrix(A)
```

but how do i change my solver to work with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How large and sparse is `A`?

It looks like `A` is just a constant in this function:

```
def to_solver_function(time,vector):
    sendoff = np.dot(A, np.transpose(vector))
    return sendoff
```

Is `vector` 1d?  Then `np.transpose(vector)` does nothing.

For calculation purposes you want

```
Asparse = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
```

Does `np.dot(Asparse, vector)` work? `np.dot` is supposed to be sparse aware.  If not,  try `Asparse*vector`. This probably produces a dense matrix, so you may need `(Asparse*vector).A1` to produce a 1d array.

But check the timings.  `Asparse` needs to quite large and very sparse to perform faster than `A` in a dot product.